# How to allow users to search my database from a WordPress web page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a database of some entities (to warn people from them, scan fraud, etc.) and provide a search box when some one searches.

It will tell him if this entity is included in this fraud list, and why to show for an example a source of the warning if no source it won't show it

I'm so confused I can't even start, should it be just normal listing and user can just do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>... or I have to do it more creatively

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

First you haven't provided a structure of the database so I added some example colums like websitename, url and added_at

You first need a Database connection

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=fraud"; "mysqlusername, "mysqlpassword");
```

Then you need a search form

```
<form action="index.php?search=1" method="GET">
Search query: <input type="text" name="query"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

After that you need to get the entries from the MySQL Database.

```
if(isset($_GET["search"])) {
    $stmnt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE websitename = ? OR url = ?");
    $stmnt->execute(array($_GET["query"], $_GET["query"]));
    // Print values
    while($row = $stmnt->fetch()) {
        echo $row["websitename"];
        echo $row["url"];
        echo $row["added_at"];
    }
}
```